# Memory Leak with ShareActionProvider?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, shareactionprovider

**StrictMode** detects a memory leak with **ShareActionProvider**, whenever there's an orientation change

```
01-30 21:26:41.466 4411-4411/com.android.example E/StrictMode: class com.swag.example.ui.BookDetailActivity; instances=2; limit=1
    android.os.StrictMode$InstanceCountViolation: class com.swag.prolificlibrary.ui.BookDetailActivity; instances=2; limit=1
    at android.os.StrictMode.setClassInstanceLimit(StrictMode.java:1)
```

However, the number of instances remain **2**, even with multiple trials of orientation change

This is my ShareActionProvider implementation inside a fragment which is part of BookDetailActivity:

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_share, menu);

    MenuItem shareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(shareItem);
    if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultIntent());
    }
}

private Intent getDefaultIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, mItem.getTitle());
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mItem.getAuthor());
    return intent;
}
```

If I comment out the call to **getDefaultIntent()**, I don's see this leak.

I tried explicitly setting the intent to null in **onStop()** lifecycle method (by making it a member variable of class), but that didn't help

Is there something wrong with my implementation or is this a know issue with ShareActionProvider ? I couldn't find any existing thread on this issue.

Comment: I came across a leakcanary discussion on ShareActionProvider memory leak: https://github.com/square/leakcanary/issues/47#issuecomment-100922839 and a Google Bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=172659. Still trying to figure out if this is applicable for my case

Comment: Faced this issue again with ShareActionProvider, Just used the code snippet for share URL http://guides.codepath.com/android/Sharing-Content-with-Intents#attach-share-for-a-webview-url and observed the same Activity Leak reported by StrictMode